# Why is it on startup it takes me to a terminal login and vty instead of lightdm?

Tags: 12.10

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 but when I restarted my laptop (dell d630, intel core duo, 8 GB of ram) it now starts ubuntu on this coding screen that I don't quite understand.

Sorry if this is a bad question to ask but I really don't understand, when I start it up every time I end up on a black screen that asks for my login info, I type that in and then it just stays on the black screen and I can run commands but I can't get the actual system to starup, can someone please help?

Comment: Sounds like you upgraded with a server iso.

Answer (score 0):

With the symptoms you are describing, I can think of two possible causes.

**Display manager not starting**

This is the easy one: Try running `sudo service lightdm start`. If this gives you your regular graphical desktop, we can look into why `lightdm` isn't started automatically.

**Missing desktop environment**

If the above didn't help, you are probably missing your desktop environment. Luckily, reinstalling is easy: Run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. That will probably prompt to install lots of packages. Allow the installation, wait for it to finish, then reboot.

<sub>For future reference: That 'coding screen' is a terminal.</sub>